# How to shrink UILabel spacing between lines without label being clipped?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, constraints

I have a label which I am trying to shrink the spacing in between lines. I tried many things including changing the height multiple, min/max line spacing etc. When I changed the heigh multiple the label seemed to get clipped on top. I'm adding images to show as an example:

`This is a regular attributed label with default settings.
Constraints: Leading 20, trailing 20, align center to Superview and Align Y to superview`

[image]

`This is the same label but with the height Multiple set at 0.7 which actually shrinks the letter spacing like I want. The issue is that the top of the label is clipped and not adjusted to fit right`

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this use of shrinking the spacing between lines but not letting the label get clipped?

Thanks ahead of time!

**EDIT:**

With the code below by Pedro the label line spacing does diminish but now my label text is clipped on the bottom like so:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Also based on Pedros answer when I increase defaultLineSpacing = 20 the label space is very weird. The top blue part expands more while the bottom is still clipped off like so :

[image]

Comment: Just try ‘sizeToFit’ and make sure you have not added height constraint. Otherwise I don’t see any issue there

Comment: I guess label shrinks because of height constraint multiple is set to 0.7. Please remove height constraint and set number of lines to 0, which should resolve this issue. I know i am late to answer but thought to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass a UILabel with the following and replace MINIMUM_SIZE and MAX_SIZE with your minimum desired font size and the max.

```
class LabelWithAdaptiveTextHeight: UILabel {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    font = fontToFitHeight()
}

private func fontToFitHeight() -> UIFont {

    var minFontSize: CGFloat = MINIMUM_SIZE
    var maxFontSize: CGFloat = MAX_SIZE
    var fontSizeAverage: CGFloat = 0
    var textAndLabelHeightDiff: CGFloat = 0

    while (minFontSize <= maxFontSize) {

        fontSizeAverage = minFontSize + (maxFontSize - minFontSize) / 2

        guard let charsCount = text?.count, charsCount > 0 else {
            break
        }

        if let labelText: String = text {
            let labelHeight = frame.size.height

            let testStringHeight = labelText.size(withAttributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font: font.withSize(fontSizeAverage)]).height

            textAndLabelHeightDiff = labelHeight - testStringHeight

            if (fontSizeAverage == minFontSize || fontSizeAverage == maxFontSize) {
                if (textAndLabelHeightDiff < 0) {
                    return font.withSize(fontSizeAverage - 1)
                }
                return font.withSize(fontSizeAverage)
            }

            if (textAndLabelHeightDiff < 0) {
                maxFontSize = fontSizeAverage - 1

            } else if (textAndLabelHeightDiff > 0) {
                minFontSize = fontSizeAverage + 1

            } else {
                return font.withSize(fontSizeAverage)
            }
        }
    }
    return font.withSize(fontSizeAverage)
}
```

}

Comment: Ill try this out. Essentially I just want to choose how my space between each line of text it has.

Comment: The code you provided shrinks the text spacing but the label is still clipped on the bottom now. Please refer to my image above.

Comment: Please check both edits I posted with my question. That code you sent doesn't seem to be woking out right

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to just add a height constraint to the label.

Comment: Yes but my label is set to 0 lines meaning it can grow to multiple lines